# Trouble installing additional driver

Tags: installation, drivers, ati, graphics, fglrx

I tried to enable ATI/AMD FGLRX graphic driver (I'm currently using ATI Mobility Radeon HD 5470 Graphics card.) using System / Administration / Additional Drivers. However, every time I tried, I got the message something like "Install failed. Check `/var/log/jockey.log` log file."

I can't paste the entire log, since its length is more than 5 times of maximum length of question. In the log, I found that the first error of the log is `ERROR: modinfo: could not find module fglrx`. Below is first parts of the log file.

```
2011-06-26 18:54:05,662 DEBUG: fglrx is not the alternative in use
2011-06-26 18:54:05,708 DEBUG: fglrx is not the alternative in use
2011-06-26 18:54:05,747 DEBUG: fglrx is not the alternative in use
2011-06-26 18:54:13,166 DEBUG: fglrx is not the alternative in use
2011-06-26 18:54:16,365 DEBUG: Installing package: linux-headers-2.6.32-30-generic
2011-06-26 18:54:16,600 DEBUG: Package linux-headers-2.6.32-30-generic does not exist, aborting
2011-06-26 18:54:16,733 DEBUG: Installing package: fglrx
2011-06-26 18:54:44,051 DEBUG: install progress statusChange dpkg-exec 0.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:44,411 DEBUG: install progress statusChange patch 0.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:44,512 DEBUG: install progress statusChange patch 4.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:46,599 DEBUG: install progress statusChange patch 8.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:46,697 DEBUG: install progress statusChange patch 12.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:47,028 DEBUG: install progress statusChange dkms 12.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:47,128 DEBUG: install progress statusChange dkms 16.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:48,023 DEBUG: install progress statusChange dkms 20.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:48,088 DEBUG: install progress statusChange dkms 24.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:48,409 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fakeroot 24.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:48,510 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fakeroot 28.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:49,331 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fakeroot 32.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:49,447 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fakeroot 36.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:49,877 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx 36.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:49,977 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx 40.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:53,823 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx 44.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:53,896 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx 48.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:54,095 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx-amdcccle 48.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:54,196 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx-amdcccle 52.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:54,968 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx-amdcccle 56.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:55,051 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx-amdcccle 60.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:55,145 DEBUG: install progress statusChange man-db 60.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:57,608 DEBUG: install progress statusChange ureadahead 60.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:57,953 DEBUG: install progress statusChange dpkg-exec 60.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:58,022 DEBUG: install progress statusChange patch 60.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:58,119 DEBUG: install progress statusChange patch 64.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:58,202 DEBUG: install progress statusChange patch 68.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:58,268 DEBUG: install progress statusChange dkms 68.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:59,127 DEBUG: install progress statusChange dkms 72.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:59,197 DEBUG: install progress statusChange dkms 76.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:59,269 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fakeroot 76.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:59,352 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fakeroot 80.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:59,462 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fakeroot 84.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:59,563 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx 84.000000
2011-06-26 18:54:59,848 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx 88.000000
2011-06-26 18:55:37,663 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx 92.000000
2011-06-26 18:55:38,080 DEBUG: install progress statusChange python-gmenu 92.000000
2011-06-26 18:55:38,656 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx-amdcccle 92.000000
2011-06-26 18:55:38,747 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx-amdcccle 96.000000
2011-06-26 18:55:38,814 DEBUG: install progress statusChange fglrx-amdcccle 100.000000
2011-06-26 18:55:38,889 DEBUG: install progress statusChange initramfs-tools 100.000000
2011-06-26 18:55:45,978 DEBUG: install progress statusChange libc-bin 100.000000
2011-06-26 18:55:46,237 DEBUG: install progress statusChange python-support 100.000000
2011-06-26 18:55:48,242 DEBUG: Selecting previously deselected package patch.
(Reading database ... 201909 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking patch (from .../patch_2.6-2ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package dkms.
Unpacking dkms (from .../dkms_2.1.1.2-3ubuntu1.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package fakeroot.
Unpacking fakeroot (from .../fakeroot_1.14.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package fglrx.
Unpacking fglrx (from .../fglrx_2%3a8.780-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
Selecting previously deselected package fglrx-amdcccle.
Unpacking fglrx-amdcccle (from .../fglrx-amdcccle_2%3a8.780-0ubuntu2_amd64.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Setting up patch (2.6-2ubuntu1) ...
Setting up dkms (2.1.1.2-3ubuntu1.1) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.14.4-1ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode.
Setting up fglrx (2:8.780-0ubuntu2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/fglrx/ld.so.conf to provide /etc/ld.so.conf.d/GL.conf (gl_conf) in auto mode.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.32-30-generic
Loading new fglrx-8.780 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building for 2.6.32-30-generic and 2.6.35-28-generic
Building for architecture x86_64
Module build for the currently running kernel was skipped since the
kernel source for this kernel does not seem to be installed.
Building initial module for 2.6.35-28-generic
Done.

fglrx.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/2.6.35-28-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.......

DKMS: install Completed.
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for python-gmenu ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/desktop.POSIX.cache...
Setting up fglrx-amdcccle (2:8.780-0ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-2.6.35-28-generic
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for python-support ...

2011-06-26 18:55:48,391 WARNING: modinfo for module fglrx failed: ERROR: modinfo: could not find module fglrx

2011-06-26 18:55:48,391 WARNING: /sys/module/fglrx/drivers does not exist, cannot rebind fglrx driver
2011-06-26 18:55:48,391 ERROR: XorgDriverHandler.enable(): package or module not installed, aborting
```

What caused this error? How can I install the driver?

Comment: You could try pasting your log output at [pastebin.ubuntu.com](http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/) and post a link to it in your question, in place of all that scrolling text.

Comment: [Bug #870560: installing fglrx (post-release updates) fails](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/jockey/+bug/870560)

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you can try installing the newest ATI fglrx drivers manually. The following website is an unofficial wiki for ATI drivers. I am using Radeon 5650, and Catalyst 12.1 on Ubuntu 11.10. Unity 3D works smooth.

*The CPU fan isn't that over-loaded compared with no GPU installed*, according to my own experience.

This [link](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Main_Page) is from the official [ATI catalyst page](http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx).

Hit the link *Unofficial Wiki for the AMD Linux Driver* to get you there. The wiki page contains step-by-step instructions for Linux installation.

Answer (score 1):

When presented the additional driver options in the GUI jockey interface, do you have 2 options?

1. ATI/AMD proprietary graphics driver (post-release updates)
2. ATI/AMD proprietary graphics driver

so, if you're trying option 1 it will not work as the bug above shows. 
option 2 installs. And it uses the fglrx driver for the ATI card, but usability and control center is absent for me until aticongfig is run. That however crashes everything. An option is to continue the use of radeon open source driver. 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver

Answer (score 0):

This may not qualify as an answer, so forgive me if it's inappropriate...

I have a Radeon 5450 with the same problem.  The post-release updates won't install, and this has been reported on launchpad, as Tim mentioned.  The 2nd option always worked for me, but I found a problem with it - shutdown would crash at least half the time (another known problem).  So, I decided to forgo the drivers, and for me, there is absolutely no discernible downside, and shutdown always works.

So, if you don't need the drivers, I'd advise against installing them.  For me, everything works well, but I don't play any games or put heavy demands on my system.  I just use Compiz for a few of the productivity improvements, and that's all I care about.